# Evaluate CDF and outliers of multidimensional Gaussian mixture

Tags: bayesian, outliers, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I use Gaussian mixture model (GMM) to infer probability density of multidimensional data written as:
$p(x) = \sum_{j=1}^{K}\pi_j*N(x|\bf \mu_j, \Sigma_j)$, where $K$ is a number of mixtures, $\pi_j$ are their mixing coefficients and $\bf \mu_j, \Sigma_j$ are corresponding mean vectors and covariance matrices. These parameters are calculated as a result of GMM.

Then, I want to identify data outliers based on the fitted density. I am aware of several methods but here I want to define outliers as points that fall below 5% percentile. In case of univariate Gaussian, such points would be defined as: $|x-\mu| > 2\sigma$. In case of a multivariate Gaussian , one has to introduce Mahalanobis distance $d = \sqrt{(\bf x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(\bf x-\mu)}$, which defines how far a point is from the Gaussian mean. Note that $d$ is an Euclidean distance in whitened, principal components based coordinates, so can be used as a measure of deviation from the mean. To handle multiple dimensions $n$, one uses the fact that $d^2$ follows univariate $\chi^2(d^2, n)$ distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom. $CDF$ for $\chi^2$ is easily computed, given $d$ and $n$. This gives us the procedure to identify if a data point is a candidate outlier: first, we determine $d$ and then extract $CDF$ based on $\chi^2$. If $CDF > 0.95$, then we flag this point.

Though it is straightforward to do for one Gaussian, I am struggling to understand how it can be done in the case of the Gaussian mixture? Can we essentially compute CDF of the Gaussian mixture based on CDFs of its constituents?

Comment: In multiple dimensions there is uncertainty about defining the boundary that would correspond to the critical value in one-dimensional case. In other words, there are different possibilities for choosing a region where the points can be with low probability (and hence outliers.) This choice should be motivated by the actual underlying problem.

Comment: @RogerV, tbh I didn't understand your comment, Mahalanobis distance and its $\chi^2$  distribution basically gives you the direct analogy with one-dimensional case based on CDF. As I wrote I am aware of different possibilities to define the outlier criteria but I wanted to explore a specific one: 5% percentile. The question has 2 assumptions:  1) fitted GMM is correct. Also note that I want to determine the boundary based on the fitted density not the data itself; 2) 5% percentile criteria to choose an outlier is satisfactory

Comment: You are right about Mahalanobis... but Mahalanobis distance is specific to a multivariate Gaussian. You say that, if $d>d_cr$ it is an outlier (can be translated in percentiles). This criterion defines a curve in the variable space, anything outside of which is an outlier. There are more robust methods for Gaussian - like Minimal covariance determinant. But for a general multimodal multivariate distribution Mahalanobis is not applicable - you need some equivalent, i.e., you need to define another boundary (which does not necessarily has a criteria like distance associated with it.)

Comment: @RogerV, right, I see your point. But we don't have a general multimodal distribution, rather Gaussian mixture with known parameters. So the question is, using this fact can we derive a criteria similar to Mahalanobis, e.g. sum of CDFs weighted by corresponding mixture coefficients $CDF_{total}=\sum_{j=1}^{K}\pi_j*CDF_j$? $CDF_j$ would be extracted from corresponding Mahalanobis's.

Comment: I think you need an insight from the underlying problem (physical, biological, etc.)

Comment: @RogerV. I don't have any particular data, just generating it randomly. I just consider this problem from purely mathematical perspective where I assume the rule to define outliers (5% percentile). The validity of this rule is out of scope.

Comment: The 5% rule is not sufficient. Even for a one-dimensional Gaussian one has infinite number of choices for a region where the data falls with less than 5% probability. But the usual approach is to defined a boundary (which is just one or two points in 1 dimension) with everything falling outside of it being an outlier.

Comment: @RogerV. right, but why this is wrong to do in multidimensional case with Mahalanobis which basically defines an ellipsoidal boundary?

Comment: I am not saying that it is wrong (for a single Gaussian) - but it is also a specific boundary choice. Its main motivation is that the results are far from the expected mean - but this reasoning doesn't work for a mixture.

Comment: Mathematically, "outlier" has no definition.  The very concept is relative to some particular analytical perspective.

Comment: @whuber, I understand this and clearly mentioned it several times: I am interested only in a particular perspective that I described

Comment: The difficulty is that you are confusing the problem with proposed solutions.  If indeed your question is to find the lower 5th percentile of the Mahalanobis distance of a distribution, then just compute it.  But it sounds rather like you are searching for some kind of multidimensional analog of a lower percentile, but you haven't characterized the problem with sufficient clarity for us to know how to make that generalization.

Comment: @whuber, the question explicitly asks how to compute it. I mentioned that I am aware of different outliers definitions and want to concentrate of 5th percentile. I explicitly stated that the distribution is Gaussian mixture. Then I explained that I know how to compute the percentile based on Mahalanobis  for only one Gaussian but don't know if it is possible to do for the mixture with known coefficients. If it is not possible, one can simply give mathematically justified answer instead of throwing generic non-related to the question replies like "outliers problem is now well defined etc.".

Comment: After rereading this post several times, along with your comments, I think I see what you are asking: namely, how to compute the distribution of the Mahalanobis distance for a Gaussian mixture. The difficulty is that your question is effectively buried among all the other incidental points you are raising.  Rather than requiring all readers to go through that hermeneutical effort, why not clarify and simplify your question?  BTW, *of course* it's possible to compute the distribution you ask about.  I can't tell what distinction you intend by "mathematically justified answer," though.

Comment: @whuber, I see your point. Though I don't ask to compute the Mahalanobis for the mixture (I am not even sure if one can define it for the mixture) but rather CDF. In turn, I assume that it can be done based on CDFs of Gaussian constituents, that in turn are computed based on Mahalanobis distances of each constituent. I have edited the question

Comment: I do not understand the distinction you make between a mixture distribution and a CDF.  The CDF is merely one way to specify the distribution.

Comment: The problem with this question is that a Gaussian mixture is topologically more complicated than a single Gaussian. With a 1-d Gaussian you can look at a percentile of the Gaussian CDF. With a multivariate Gaussian you have a multivariate CDF that isn't so easy but because of the elliptically symmetric shape it can be boiled down to a 1-d $\chi^2$ for the Mahalanobis distance. But a mixture often has several hills and valleys and the shape of the "non-outlier region" (following your definition) cannot be easily boiled down to be represented by a 1-d CDF.

Comment: In principle, if you had a numerical way to compute the required integral under the mixture density $f$, for a given percentage $q$ you could try to find the threshold value $d$ so that $P(Q_d)=q$ where $Q_d=\{f\le d\}$ (region with low density). The set $Q_d$ would be your "outlier region", but finding $d$ is numerically hard. You won't have a simple 1-d CDF of which you'd just have to find a percentile due to the complicated topological structure of the mixture.

Comment: @ChristianHennig, thanks for the comment! Can we somehow use the property that CDF of linear combination of distributions is a linear combination of CDFs?

Comment: @AntonBaranikov I doubt it. You wrote "somehow", I don't know how, which doesn't necessarily mean it's impossible. But chances are you won't find anything simple in the literature because it's not an easy problem. Particularly it's easier to base an outlier definition on the density (low density regions) than on the CDF; with a single Gaussian you can translate one easily into the other, but it's not so simple with mixtures.

Comment: @ChristianHennig, I see! Any advice for a good strategy then? To clarify: I want first to fit GMM to a training data. Then I want to check similarity of a new testing data batch with training data. I thought, that I could define density threshold corresponding to 5% percentile (this would of course results in some outliers in the training data, but these are the false ones since GMM assumes no outliers). Then if a testing data batch has too many points (how many -  one has to define yet another threshold) falling below the density threshold then it can be flagged

Comment: @AntonBaranikov This is another question on its own, so you better start a new one.

Comment: @ChristianHennig, please check this out https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/631358/identify-outliers-in-testing-data-based-on-trained-gaussian-mixture-model/631366#631366